Show cropping region along multiple images cropped to that region
I have been trying this for a while without success. I want to show multiple images side by side that follow this specific pattern from left to right:

Full image with a rectangle showing the region of interest (ROI)
Zoomed version of the ROI
Zoomed version of the ROI for other image
...

An example would look like this. Ideally, I would like an arbitrary number of zoomed images


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you tried so far. There are a lot of different approaches to this, so it is crucial to know which packages you are planning to use. Please help others help you and provide a minimal working example.

I managed to do it. I'll leave my answer here in case it is useful
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    image/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
]
    \newcommand{\subfig}[2][0px 0px 0px 0px]{\includegraphics[height=3cm, trim=#1, clip]{#2}}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xone}{0.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yone}{0.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{0.4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{0.4}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\trimleft}{(\xone + 1) / 2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\trimdown}{(\yone + 1) / 2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\trimright}{1 - (\xtwo + 1) / 2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\trimup}{1 - (\ytwo + 1) / 2}
    
    \node [image]    (col1-row1) at (0,0)  {\subfig{duck.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(col1-row1.east)},y={(col1-row1.north)}]
        \draw[blue,thick] (\xone, \yone) rectangle (\xtwo,\ytwo);
    \end{scope}
    
    \node [image, right=0.15cm]    (col2-row1) at (col1-row1.east)  {\adjustbox{cframe=blue 0.2pt, height=3cm, trim={\trimleft\width} {\trimdown\height} {\trimright\width} {\trimup\height},clip} {\subfig{duck.jpg}}};
    
    \node [image, right=0.15cm]    (col3-row1) at (col2-row1.east)  {\adjustbox{cframe=blue 0.2pt, height=3cm, trim={\trimleft\width} {\trimdown\height} {\trimright\width} {\trimup\height},clip} {\subfig{duck.jpg}}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}%

